# JSFiddle throwing modulerr error; Why is this Angular App broken?

Tags: angularjs, controller, jsfiddle

I have this angular app in JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/horacebury/kvsek6sw/

Why is it throwing the modulerr error?

The HTML is properly formed:

```
<div ng-app="App">
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
    <div id="tablecontainer">
      <table class="tgh">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th><p>Auxilliary Power</p></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>
      <div id="handscontainer">
        <div id="example"></div>
      </div>
      <table class="tg">
        <tr>
          <td style="width: 146px;"></td>
          <td class="tg-yw4l" ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">{{item}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div id="TrendChart"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the module and controller statement is correctly structured, with the external references all present:

```
angular.module('App', [])
.controller("TodoCtrl", ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope,$timeout) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the angular module loaded, you need to put it "inline" in the body (Actualy in onLoad event).

Change the javascript option "LOAD TYPE" to "No load - wrap in body"

https://jsfiddle.net/kvsek6sw/1/

```
<div ng-app="App">
</div>

<script>
 //your angular module
</sctipt>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is just a small JSFiddle config you have to do:

In the JavaScript window, go to

> Parameters > Load-type > No wrap - in `<body>`

[image]

## [Fixed Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4reychxy/)